# How to perform a numpy function with a numpy array of numpy array objects?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say we have a function for creating numpy arrays of numpy array objects:

```
randarr = lambda shape: np.random.randint(0, 10, shape)
get_numpy_array_obj = lambda shapes: \
    np.array([randarr(shape) for shape in shapes])
```

and also the defined sizes of the arrays:

```
shapes = [(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)]
```

Because the shapes of the arrays is not the same, numpy treats the other arrays as objects.

Now if we create two of these arrays

```
A = get_numpy_array_obj(shapes)
B = get_numpy_array_obj(shapes)
```

doing simple operations like +, -, ** etc. is not a problem, e.g.:

```
C = A * B - (A + B)**2
```

The problem occurs when I want to apply a numpy function on these arrays like tanh, exp etc.

```
D = np.tanh(A)
```

This returns to me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tanh'
```

I could apply the function on each array one-by-one like this

```
D = np.array([np.tanh(a) for a in A])
```

My idea was to write less code and more readable.

Also `np.vectorize(np.tanh)(A)` was not working. This would return:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is there an other possible way to apply a numpy function on an array of numpy array objects?

Comment: Not really, I don't think. From Numpy's perspective there's no such thing as an "array of arrays".  It just sees it as a (possibly) hetereogeneous array of Python objects, so it doesn't necessarily know how to vectorize operations across them. You might consider a different data structure, such as sparse matrices or something, depending on your application.  Otherwise you can iterate over the array in apply operations on the arrays one by one--there's no real disadvantage in this case.

Comment: I need this for machine learning specifically (for the weight between the layers). This type of operation is used many times and also for huge array sizes. Can I get somehow a better performance other than the list comprehension thing what I have in my question written?

Comment: try np.frompyfunc

Comment: Your answer was really helpful! `np.frompyfunc(np.tanh, 1, 1)` can be used instead of `np.tanh`. Could you please give an answer for this question with little detail  or a link for `np.frompyfunc` and an example? (for accepting the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [99]: arr = np.array([np.ones(ij) for ij in [(1,3),(2,4),(3,2)]])
In [100]: arr
Out[100]: 
array([array([[1., 1., 1.]]),
       array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]]),
       array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])], dtype=object)
```

Operators like '+' work because arrays have the corresponding methods:

```
In [101]: arr[0].__add__
Out[101]: <method-wrapper '__add__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0xb64897a0>
In [102]: arr+arr
Out[102]: 
array([array([[2., 2., 2.]]),
       array([[2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.]]),
       array([[2., 2.],
       [2., 2.],
       [2., 2.]])], dtype=object)
```

But functions like `np.tanh` don't have array methods.

`frompyfunc` passes elements of an array to your function and returns a object dtype array.  Usually that's a pain, but in this case it's just what we want:

```
In [103]: np.frompyfunc(np.tan,1,1)(arr)
Out[103]: 
array([array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772]]),
       array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772]]),
       array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772]])], dtype=object)
```

`vectorize` also uses `frompyfunc` but tries to convert the results to a numeric array.  We can skip that by specifying an `otypes`:

```
In [104]: np.vectorize(np.tan,otypes='O')(arr)
Out[104]: 
array([array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772]]),
       array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772, 1.55740772]]),
       array([[1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772],
       [1.55740772, 1.55740772]])], dtype=object)
```

Iteration on object arrays is between list iteration and numeric array iteration in speed.  It has some of the array overhead, but not all.  The elements are pointers, just as in lists.

`frompyfunc` can be a bit faster (up to 2x) than explicit iteration.  `vectorize` is a bit slower because it has some overhead.  The big advantage of these functions is that they handle broadcasting.  Do your own timings to see if they help.