# When is np.vecotrize useful

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, vectorization

I am wondering when should we use np.vectorize over lambda, for example suppose I want to do the following operation over each element of numpy array for which I have lambda like

```
f1 = lambda x: x / 12.92 if x < .03928 else ((x + .055) / 1.055) ** 2.4
```

and I vectorize it as

```
f2 = np.vectorize(f1)
```

My observations were that f1 performs better than f2. I tried researching on this but could not understand correctly, can anyone point to any good reference or could give an example when vectorize will be useful.

Comment: Have you actually measured the speed difference? I would expect Numpy to be faster because it is built in C

Comment: @Simon Not true for `np.vectorize()`, it's essentially a `for` loop in Python.

Comment: `f2` may be useful if `f1` only works with scalar values. Or in the case I just answered https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853179/901925

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, I think I understand better now